# Multiple request triggered when used browser but not when used java httpclient

Tags: browser, apache-httpclient-4.x

Here is my application cloud environment. 
I have ELB with sticky session -> 2 HA Proxy -> 1 Machines which hosts my application on jboss.

I am processing a request which takes more than 1 minute. I am logging IP addresses at the start of the processing request. 
When i process this request through browser, I see that duplicate request is being logged after 1 minute and few seconds. If first request routes from the HAProxy1 then another request routes from HAProxy2. On browser I get HttpStatus=0 response after 2.1 minute

My hypotesis is that ELB is triggering this duplicate request.
Kindly help me to verify this hypothesis.

When I use the Apache Http Client for same request, I do not see duplicate request being triggered. Also I get exception after 1 minute and few seconds.
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond

Kindly help me to understand what is happening over here.
-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By ELB I presume you are referring to Amazon AWS's Elastic Load Balancer.

Elastic Load Balancer has a built-in request time-out of 60 seconds, which cannot be changed.  The browser has smart re-try logic, hence you're seeing two requests, but your server should be processing them as two separate unrelated requests, so this actually makes matters worse.  Using httpclient, the timeout causes the NoHttpResponseException, and no retry is used.

The solution is to either improve the performance of your request on the server, or have the initial request fire off a background task, and then a supplemental request (possibly using AJAX) which polls for completion.